# Graph Api Not Getting Location from Facebook SDK in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK in my Android App. And I need to get all the information of the user. By now I'm able to get the Name ID Email Birthday and the profile pic of the user. The last one that I need to get is the location or current location of the user. I'm using this code below.

```
if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);

            JSONObject obj = null;
            URL img = null;


             try {
                    String jsonUser = fb.request("me");
                    obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
                    String id = obj.optString("id");
                    String name = obj.optString("name");
                    String bday = obj.optString("birthday");
                    String address = obj.optString("location");
                    String email = obj.optString("email");
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt)).setText("Welcome! "+name);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtbday)).setText("Birthday: "+bday);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtaddress)).setText("Address: "+address);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtemail)).setText("Email: "+email);
                    img = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=normal");
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        }else{
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_button);
        }
    }
```

Here are the permissions

```
fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,new String[] {"email", "user_location", "user_birthday","publish_stream"}, new DialogListener() {

                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
                }

                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    updateButtonImage();
                }

                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                }
            });
        }
```

Thanks for who will help in advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Graph API Explorer tool is a great way to see what the response of a graph API endpoint is.  Just request the right permissions (such as `user_location`) by clicking "Get Access Token" and see the output of '/me'.  When I get an access token with the `user_location` permission I am able to see my current

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

To get the current location, this is how to do it:

```
String currentCity = obj.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
```

With newer SDKs you can get location detail by passing as below with graph API object

```
graphObject.getInnerJSONObject().getJSONObject("location").getString("id"))
```

Comment: I tried the coed that you post but still the value is still null.

Comment: thanks it works I tried everything that I search and I thought they are all not working until I tried to clear the data/cache in my emulator and finally it works!  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download source code from here ([Get location of facebook user using Graph API in android](https://wordpress.com/posts/deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com))

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:text="Email"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="DOB"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:text="DOB"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_dob"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_email"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Location"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:text="location"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_location"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#6585C8"
        android:id="@+id/ll_facebook"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
            android:id="@+id/iv_facebook"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tv_facebook"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package facebooklocation.facebooklocation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ImageView iv_image, iv_facebook;
    TextView tv_name, tv_email, tv_dob, tv_location, tv_facebook;
    LinearLayout ll_facebook;
    String str_facebookname, str_facebookemail, str_facebookid, str_birthday, str_location;
    boolean boolean_login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        getKeyHash();
        listener();
    }


    private void init() {
        iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        iv_facebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_facebook);
        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_dob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
        tv_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        tv_facebook = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_facebook);
        ll_facebook = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_facebook);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    }

    private void listener() {
        tv_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void facebookLogin() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.e("ONSUCCESS", "User ID: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                        + "\n" + "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {

                                    boolean_login = true;
                                    tv_facebook.setText("Logout from Facebook");

                                    Log.e("object", object.toString());
                                    str_facebookname = object.getString("name");

                                    try {
                                        str_facebookemail = object.getString("email");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_facebookemail = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                        str_facebookid = object.getString("id");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_facebookid = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    }


                                    try {
                                        str_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_birthday = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonobject_location = object.getJSONObject("location");
                                        str_location = jsonobject_location.getString("name");

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_location = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    fn_profilepic();

                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email,gender,birthday,location");

                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
                    return; // already logged out
                }
                new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
                        .Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email"));
                        facebookLogin();

                    }
                }).executeAsync();


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.e("ON ERROR", "Login attempt failed.");


                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    private void getKeyHash() {
        // Add code to print out the key hash
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("facebooklocation.facebooklocation", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
    }

    private void fn_profilepic() {

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
        params.putString("type", "large");
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "me/picture",
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.e("Response 2", response + "");

                        try {
                            String str_facebookimage = (String) response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("data").get("url");
                            Log.e("Picture", str_facebookimage);

                            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(str_facebookimage).skipMemoryCache(true).into(iv_image);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        tv_name.setText(str_facebookname);
                        tv_email.setText(str_facebookemail);
                        tv_dob.setText(str_birthday);
                        tv_location.setText(str_location);

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (boolean_login) {
            boolean_login = false;
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            tv_location.setText("");
            tv_dob.setText("");
            tv_email.setText("");
            tv_name.setText("");
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.profile).into(iv_image);
            tv_facebook.setText("Login with Facebook");
        } else {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location"));
            facebookLogin();
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    }
}
```

Thanks!