# Unable to get user location from Facebook SDK Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I want to get the location of user in my android application through Facebook login.I implemented login and everything is working fine other than location(Location which user updates in his profile as "Lives in").I retrieved username and id using this.I set permission also.But its not working.Please help me.

Here is my class

```
public class FacebookActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    Facebook fb;
    //ImageView pic;

    CircularImageView pic;
    ImageView button;
    TextView welcome,location;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    String APP_ID = "xxxxxxxx";
    String name;
    String id;
    String town;
    String currentCity;
    String imgurl_check;
    Drawable d ;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String access_token;


    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);

            sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            access_token = sp.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);

            if(access_token !=null)
            {
                fb.setAccessToken(access_token);

            }
            if(expires !=0)
            {
                fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }

            button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login);
            welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
            //pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture_pic);
            pic = (CircularImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture_pic);

            button.setOnClickListener(this);

            updateButtonImage();

        }

     private void updateButtonImage() 
        {
         if(fb.isSessionValid())
            {
                //button.setImageResource(R.drawable.fb_logout);
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                new GetProfileName().execute();
                new LoadProfileImage(pic)
                .execute("https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?width=200&height=200&method=GET&access_token="
                        + access_token);

                //pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                    }
         else
         {
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.fb_login);
                welcome.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }


private class GetProfileName extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
         protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls)
         {

            JSONObject obj = null;
            JSONObject obj1 = null;

            URL img_url = null;

            String jsonUser;
            String jsonPicture;

                try {
                    jsonUser = fb.request("me");
                    obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
                    id = obj.optString("id");
                    name = obj.optString("name");
                    currentCity = obj.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");

                 Log.d("Executing thread",id);
                 Log.d("Executing thread",name);
                 Log.d("Executing thread",currentCity);



                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



          return null;

             }
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

             }
         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {



             location.setText(currentCity);
             location.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                welcome.setText(name);
                welcome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

                editor.putString("UserName", name);

                editor.commit();


             }
        }

/**
* Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
* */
  private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    CircularImageView bmImage;

  public LoadProfileImage(CircularImageView bmImage) {
this.bmImage = bmImage;

}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

String urldisplay = urls[0];
Bitmap mIcon11 = null;

try {

    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return mIcon11;



}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File mFolder = new File(extr + "/App");

if (!mFolder.exists()) {
    mFolder.mkdir();
}

String s = "myfile.png";

File f = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(),s);

String strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,70, fos);

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
 //   MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(fb.isSessionValid())
        {
                    try {
                        fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                        updateButtonImage();

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
     else
     {
            //login to fb

            fb.authorize(FacebookActivity.this,new String[] {"email","user_hometown","user_location"},new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this,  "fberror", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this,  "onerror", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    updateButtonImage();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this,  "Oncancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any error are you getting in?

Comment: no error.just that its not being retrieved from the json

Comment: But it's present in the JSON?

Comment: @Nevaeh okay, it may possible that FB can not give that things with its new api.

Comment: @tobi But,this should contain location na...jsonUser = fb.request("me"); ??

Comment: @pratik so what should i do inorder to get the location ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194119/how-get-user-profile-information-facebook-android visit this, it may useful to you and let we see

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373794/graph-api-not-getting-location-from-facebook-sdk-in-android another one

Comment: so location can't be retrieved directly ?

Comment: @Nevaeh hmmm, have you got something from that links related to it?

Comment: I'm getting this "org.json.JSONException: No value for location"

Comment: @Nevaeh that means location tag is not there in response you getting from facebook.

Comment: @Nevaeh Just paste your json here

Comment: Please see this...                                              {
   "id": "XXXXXX",
   "email": "abcd\u0040gmail.com",
   "first_name": ABC",
   "gender": "female",
   "last_name": "DEF",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/XXXXXXXX/",
   "locale": "en_GB",
   "name": "ABC DEF",
   "timezone": -6.5,
   "updated_time": "2014-10-05T16:38:49+0000",
   "verified": true
}

Comment: @pratik could u please reply ??

Comment: @Nevaeh ya its clear that location is not coming fro facebook api.

Comment: @Nevaeh is this working or not still?

Comment: yeah.i got it working.i had permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

Download source code from here:

https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/04/07/get-location-of-facebook-user-using-graph-api-in-android/

Add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:text="Email"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="DOB"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:text="DOB"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_dob"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_email"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Location"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:text="location"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_location"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#6585C8"
        android:id="@+id/ll_facebook"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
            android:id="@+id/iv_facebook"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tv_facebook"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package facebooklocation.facebooklocation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ImageView iv_image, iv_facebook;
    TextView tv_name, tv_email, tv_dob, tv_location, tv_facebook;
    LinearLayout ll_facebook;
    String str_facebookname, str_facebookemail, str_facebookid, str_birthday, str_location;
    boolean boolean_login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        getKeyHash();
        listener();
    }


    private void init() {
        iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        iv_facebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_facebook);
        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_dob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
        tv_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        tv_facebook = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_facebook);
        ll_facebook = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_facebook);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    }

    private void listener() {
        tv_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void facebookLogin() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.e("ONSUCCESS", "User ID: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                        + "\n" + "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {

                                    boolean_login = true;
                                    tv_facebook.setText("Logout from Facebook");

                                    Log.e("object", object.toString());
                                    str_facebookname = object.getString("name");

                                    try {
                                        str_facebookemail = object.getString("email");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_facebookemail = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                        str_facebookid = object.getString("id");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_facebookid = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    }


                                    try {
                                        str_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_birthday = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonobject_location = object.getJSONObject("location");
                                        str_location = jsonobject_location.getString("name");

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_location = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    fn_profilepic();

                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email,gender,birthday,location");

                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
                    return; // already logged out
                }
                new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
                        .Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email"));
                        facebookLogin();

                    }
                }).executeAsync();


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.e("ON ERROR", "Login attempt failed.");


                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    private void getKeyHash() {
        // Add code to print out the key hash
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("facebooklocation.facebooklocation", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
    }

    private void fn_profilepic() {

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
        params.putString("type", "large");
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "me/picture",
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.e("Response 2", response + "");

                        try {
                            String str_facebookimage = (String) response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("data").get("url");
                            Log.e("Picture", str_facebookimage);

                            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(str_facebookimage).skipMemoryCache(true).into(iv_image);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        tv_name.setText(str_facebookname);
                        tv_email.setText(str_facebookemail);
                        tv_dob.setText(str_birthday);
                        tv_location.setText(str_location);

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (boolean_login) {
            boolean_login = false;
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            tv_location.setText("");
            tv_dob.setText("");
            tv_email.setText("");
            tv_name.setText("");
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.profile).into(iv_image);
            tv_facebook.setText("Login with Facebook");
        } else {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location"));
            facebookLogin();
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    }
}
```

Thanks